# Using collection drop down select to pass id of object into session in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

At the moment, I have a list of companies drop-down in list_companies#index.What the user currently has to do is select any one company in the drop-down and click select project button. Then, when the submit button is clicked, it will pass the id of that company into the session.

My question is - how to pass the id of the selected company in the drop-down into the session.

list_companies/index:

```
<h3>Select Company</h3>
<%= simple_form_for :Select_Company, :url => {action: 'select_company'},  :method => 'post' do |f| %> 
<label for="company_name">Company Name</label> <%=render 'company_dropdown'%>
 <%= submit_tag "Select Company", :type => 'button' ,:onclick=>"getNewPage()"%>
<%end%>
<script>    
   function getNewPage()
   {  
      var form = "";
      var compId = document.getElementById("company_company_id").value;

      if (!compId)
      {
        alert("Please select a Company");
      }else
      {
        form = document.forms[0];           
        form.method = "post";
        form.action = "list_companies/select_company";
        form.submit();
      }  
   }    
</script>
```

_company_dropdown.html.erb

```
<% if @list_companies != nil then%> 
    <%= collection_select(:company, :company_id, @list_companies, :company_id, :company_name,{:selected=>@company_id,:prompt=> "Select Company"}) %>
<%else%>
    <select >
        <option value="">Select Company</option>
    </select>
<%end%>
```

list_companies_controller.rb

```
class ListCompaniesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @list_companies=Company.all

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
     end
  end

  def select_company
    company = params[:company] 
 puts "current_dashboard_user.company_id ===>" +current_dashboard_user.company_id.to_s   
    if (company != nil) then
      current_dashboard_user.company_id = company[:company_id]
      session[:current_dashboard_user] = current_dashboard_user.id
      session[:company_id] = company[:company_id]
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html {redirect_to root_url}
      end 
    else
      format.html { render :index}
    end 
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :list_companies do
    collection do
      get :select_company
      post :select_company
  end
end
```

Now company_id not stored in the session.

Comment: When i click submit button nothing will happen. @Santosh

Comment: You will need to define an ajax target that will receive your id and assign it to your session variable...

Answer (score 0):

After click on submit button user will redirect to controller action. In that action you can set session id. 
`session[:id] = params[:id]`